# Newtype Deriving Monad Error

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, newtype

I'm trying to install an application [Termite - Util](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/termite2/util/master/ContextError.hs) but I get this error in with the line 14

```
newtype CE m a = CE {unCE :: m a} deriving (Monad)
```

The error says:

> ContextError.hs:14:45:
>      No instance for (Applicative (CE m))
>        arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
>      Possible fix:
>        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
>          so you can specify the instance context yourself
>      When deriving the instance for (Monad (CE m))

I have alredy try with the solution proposed in [CIS 194: Homework 7](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions/comments/3j55zb/cis_194_homework_7/?st=j459vj72&sh=497043ff)

adding this:

> instance Applicative (CE m) where
>      pure = return
>      (<*>) = ap

but I get this error again

> ContextError.hs:14:45:
>      No instance for (Functor (CE m))
>        arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
>      Possible fix:
>       use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
>          so you can specify the instance context yourself
>      When deriving the instance for (Monad (CE m))

I really don't know how to proceed, I'm new with Haskell

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, thats because the base has changed: now `Monad` requires the type to be `Applicative`.

Comment: You probably want to use `deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)` together. It wasn't required a few years ago, but it is now.

Comment: Thanks.. It's working with `deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)`

Answer (score 2):

In ghc 7.10.1 AMP proposal took place. Prior to that you could define `Monad` instance without having `Applicative` instance, after 7.10.1 you have to define `Functor` and `Applicative` if you want to define a `Monad`.

https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal